# How to implement Rails POST API to send data to external API based on body request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, integration

I have been trying to integrate an API on a rails app.

It is structured in such a way that I have to write my own POST API to communicate back and forth with it.

For example: **POST dividebuy/api/getorderdetails**

Example Request:

```
{
  "orderId":"6667",
  "retailerStoreCode":"default",
  "storeAuthentication":"5LIH1TaW8ewd",
  "storeToken":"3aa7Sgt76sz7"
}
```

Example Response:

```
{
        "order_detail": {
        "store_order_id": "64",
        "store_order_increment_id": "145006485",
        "store_token": ENV['DIVIDEBUY_TOKEN'],
        "store_authentication": ENV['DIVIDEBUY_AUTHENTICATION'],
        "logo_url": "https://moduleinstalledmagento1.dbuytest.info/media/dividebuy/",
        "grand_total": 318.4,
        "subtotal": 265.33,
        "subtotalInclVat": 318.4,
        "discount": 0,
        "discountApplied": "beoforeVat",
        "shipping": 0,
        "shippingInclVat": 0,
        "shipping_label": "Free Shipping - Free",
        "shipping_method": "freeshipping_freeshipping",
        "is_default_shipping": 0,
        "is_default_billing": 0,
        "vat": 53.07
      },
      "product_details": [
        {
          "name": "Some product name",
          "sku": "SKU",
          "qty": "1.0000",
          "price": "249.1700",
          "priceInclVat": "299.0000",
          "rowTotal": "249.1700",
          "rowTotalInclVat": "299.0000",
          "discount": "0.0000",
          "short_description": "Some Product",
          "product_type": "simple",
          "product_weight": "35.5000",
          "product_visibility": "4",
          "DivVat": "20",
          "image_url": "some url.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "shipping_address": {
          "first_name": "name",
          "last_name": "name",
          "email": "retailer@dividebuy.co.uk",
          "street": [
              "Address 1",
              "Adress 2"
          ],
          "postcode": "DE4 3ED",
          "region": "County",
          "city": "town"
      },
      "billing_address": {
          "first_name": "name",
          "last_name": "name",
          "email": "retailer@dividebuy.co.uk",
          "street": [
              "Address 1", "Adress 2"
          ],
          "postcode": "ST15 8YR",
          "region": "County",
          "city": "town"
      }
    }
```

so the controller I have is structured like this:

```
class Dividebuy::Api::GetorderdetailsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :create

  # GET /product
  def index
    product = Spree::Product.all
    render json: product, status: 200
  end

  # POST /product
  def create

    data = {
        "order_detail": {
        "store_order_id": "64",
        "store_order_increment_id": "145006485",
        "store_token": ENV['DIVIDEBUY_TOKEN'],
        "store_authentication": ENV['DIVIDEBUY_AUTHENTICATION'],
        "logo_url": "https://moduleinstalledmagento1.dbuytest.info/media/dividebuy/",
        "grand_total": 318.4,
        "subtotal": 265.33,
        "subtotalInclVat": 318.4,
        "discount": 0,
        "discountApplied": "beoforeVat",
        "shipping": 0,
        "shippingInclVat": 0,
        "shipping_label": "Free Shipping - Free",
        "shipping_method": "freeshipping_freeshipping",
        "is_default_shipping": 0,
        "is_default_billing": 0,
        "vat": 53.07
      },
      "product_details": [
        {
          "name": "Some product name",
          "sku": "SKU",
          "qty": "1.0000",
          "price": "249.1700",
          "priceInclVat": "299.0000",
          "rowTotal": "249.1700",
          "rowTotalInclVat": "299.0000",
          "discount": "0.0000",
          "short_description": "Some Product",
          "product_type": "simple",
          "product_weight": "35.5000",
          "product_visibility": "4",
          "DivVat": "20",
          "image_url": "some url.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "shipping_address": {
          "first_name": "name",
          "last_name": "name",
          "email": "retailer@dividebuy.co.uk",
          "street": [
              "Address 1",
              "Adress 2"
          ],
          "postcode": "DE4 3ED",
          "region": "County",
          "city": "town"
      },
      "billing_address": {
          "first_name": "name",
          "last_name": "name",
          "email": "retailer@dividebuy.co.uk",
          "street": [
              "Address 1", "Adress 2"
          ],
          "postcode": "ST15 8YR",
          "region": "County",
          "city": "town"
      }
    }

    user = User.where(email: 'test@example.com')

    if user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      render json:  data, status: :created
    else
      render json: { error: "error:" }, status: 400
    end
  end

end
```

Here is what I have on my routes for this API:

```
  namespace :dividebuy, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    namespace :api do
      resources :getorderdetails, only: [:index, :create]
    end
  end
```

My question is basically from the examples given in the documentation of the **request** & **response** as shown above, what is the best way to integrate with this API communication on my rails app?
I just hardcoded some data and passed it as a response, probably there is a better way to do that.

More clarity, to test I use postman:
**localhost:3000/dividebuy/api/getorderdetails**

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I just did something similar myself, I can tell you my approach, which follows my guiding principle of "fat model skinny controller".

All the api-related structures that you show in the `GetOrderDetailsController` should be moved into a service class. Since I see the word Spree in your question, I'll call it `SpreeService`. So the first step at refactoring is to change your `GetOrderDetailsController`:

```rb
# app/controllers/dividebuy/api/get_order_details_controller.rb

def create
  spree = SpreeService.new(params)

  response = spree.create_order

  if response.errors
    # render the error page
  else
    # render the success page, with order number etc
  end
end
```

This gives the general idea, specifics depend on your app.
In the `SpreeService` class, you can further decompose the request into smaller methods. As you app develops, you will find more and more functionality to delegate to the `SpreeService` class.

```rb
# app/domain_models/spree_service.rb
require 'net/http'

class SpreeService
  BaseUrl = "api.spree.com"

  def initialize(params)
    # capture the params of interest
  end

  def create_order
    response = Net::HTTP.request(...)
  end

private
  def create_order_query
    # define the hash of all the date to make new order
  end
end
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. Shed some light and like that name: **fat model skinny controller**, has a nice ring to it.